# VBA to email multiple address's

Tags: excel, vba

If I change `c.Offset(, 1)` to `c.Offset(, 0)` an email will get sent to the first recipient but not the next. If I change `c.Offset(, 0)` to `c.Offset(, 1)` I get outlook does not recognize one or more names.  How can I get the syntax correct to send the email to multiple users?  The design of the spreadsheet is below as well as the `VB`. I apologize for the lengthy message, just trying to be complete. Thank you :).

**Design of spreadsheet**

```
A              B             C                     D
Email         Date         Comment 1             Comment 2
123@gmail.com
456@hotmail.com
```

when the spreadsheet opens the below runs automatically:

**VB**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sR As String
Dim sFile As String
Sheets("Email").Activate
Range("A1").Select
If MsgBox("Are there any issues to report", vbYesNoCancel) = vbYes Then
        Range("D2").Value = "x"
        MsgBox ("Please select an issue and save"), vbExclamation
Else
Range("C2").Value = "x"
If vbCancel Then Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True


'define path
 MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

'create connection, check condition, send email
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
With WS
 Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each c In Rng

 Msg = "For " & WS.Cells(2, 2) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
 For i = 3 To 4
 If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
    Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
 End If
Next

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = c.Offset(, 1)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
        .Body = Msg
        If Range("D2").Value & Chr(14) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
        .Send
    End With
Next c

'confirm message sent, clear sheet, and delete copy
 MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
 Range("C2:D2").ClearContents
 Kill MyFileCopy

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing

'Exit and do not save
 Application.Quit
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Because you're using `For Each c In Rng` it appears that you want to send one email per line. But from your question, it sounds like you want to send the same email to more than one email address. Can you clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: `c.Offset(, 1)` is offsetting one *column*, not one *row* which is maybe what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `.To = c` because your sent is sent to column A, which has the addresses.

There is no need to offset the `c` cell in the range at all.

If you wish to send an email to more than one address, semi-colons need to be between each address, as this is how Outlook resolves that there is more than one address.

So, based on your example above:

```
.To = c & ";" & c.Offset(1) ' & ";" c.Offset(2) to carry it further.
```

Note that I also Offset c by 1 **Row**. You wrote `c.Offset(,1)` meaning it will offset 1 column. The arguments for `Offset` are `Offset(rows,columns,[row height],[column width])`

Comment: Alternatively, in a `For` loop, OP can do `.Recipients.Add c.Offset(_iterator_).Value`

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens! That would definitely be better if there were many rows to add.

Comment: I set the `.To = c` and multiple emails get sent the issue now is the first email is correct.  I will post in a new thread.  Thank you :).