# email not correct for all recipients

Tags: excel, vba

When there are multiple users the first email sent is correct but in the second only the `For 10/23/2015` shows up.  Below is a copy of a correct email and where the data comes from and the code.

**Correct Email**

```
**For 10/2/2015** ( Msg = "For " & c.Offset(, 1) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)

**-There are no issues to report in the HLA & Molecular Diagnostics Laboratory.** (   For i = 3 To 4
        If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
            Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
        End If
    Next)
```

**VBA**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sR As String
Dim intAnswer As Integer


'open sheet
 Sheets("Email").Activate
 intAnswer = MsgBox("Are there any issues to report", vbYesNoCancel)
  Select Case intAnswer
  Case vbYes
  Range("D2").Value = "x"
  MsgBox ("Please select an issue and save"), vbExclamation
  Case vbCancel
  Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True
  Case Else
  Range("C2").Value = "x"
  End Select

'define path
 MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

'create connection, check condition, send email
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
With WS
Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 End With

 For Each c In Rng

 Msg = "For " & WS.Cells(2, 2) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
 For i = 3 To 4
 If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
    Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
 End If
 Next

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = c
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
        .Body = Msg
        If Range("D2").Value & Chr(14) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
        .Send
    End With
Next c

'confirm message sent, clear sheet, and delete copy
 MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
 Range("C2:D2").ClearContents
 Kill MyFileCopy

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing

'Exit and do not save
 Application.Quit
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 End Sub
```

Comment: related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306544/vba-to-email-multiple-addresss/33307009?noredirect=1#comment54413629_33307009)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the answer to this based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306544/vba-to-email-multiple-addresss/33307009?noredirect=1#comment54413629_33307009), where you shared your data structure. *(Otherwise, your post did not provide enough detail to be clear on what you are asking.)*

The issue you have is that as you loop through each cell in the Column A (all the emails) via `For each c in rng`, you also test the conditions of if column C or D contains `x` against each row in `If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then`. Since your data set only has the message information in row 2 (as shown in your previous question), you need to always check row 2 each time you loop.

All that said, change

```
If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
```

to

```
If LCase(WS.Cells(2, i)) = "x" Then
```

and you will get the results you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.... makes sense know but I was struggling for a few days.  Thanks again :).

Comment: Yep - We **all** experience the learning curve ... sometimes for each new concept within the same language :)